# how to merge selective column contents in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I manged to get a csv file output, but doesn't look nice and a lot of fields can be consolidated. Please help

what I have:

```
    Firewall,zone-Context,Policy,Source,Destination,Application,Action
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,172.25.41.0/24,,,
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,172.25.60.0/24,,,
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,,172.27.16.38/32,,
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,,172.27.16.48/32,,
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,,,TCP_9090,
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,,,TCP_8080,
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,,,,Permit

    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,172.25.41.0/24,,,
    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,172.25.60.0/24,,,
    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,,172.27.16.38/32,,
    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,,172.27.16.48/32,,
    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,,,TCP_9090,
    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,,,TCP_2020,
    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,,,,Permit
```

Desired output: just two lines when opened with excel or with google sheets. 
two source address and two destination addresses and two applications being grouped into a single cell preferably with line breaks at the end of each

```
    Firewall,zone-Context,Policy,Source,Destination,Application,Action
    fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,"172.25.41.0/24
    172.25.60.0/24","172.27.16.38/32
    172.27.16.48/32","TCP_9090 
    TCP_8080",Permit

    fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,"172.25.41.0/24
    172.25.60.0/24","172.27.16.38/32
    172.27.16.48/32","TCP_9090
    TCP_2020",Permit
```

for all the lines that have "Firewall,zone-Context,Policy" in common, I am trying to consolidate the respective "Source,Destination,Application,Action"

i tried with bash, it's only getting worse.

a friend has written some code seems little buggy but looking for something simple

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with Python as follows:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.csv') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(["Firewall", "zone-Context" ,"Policy" ,"Source", "Destination", "Application", "Action"])

    for k, g in groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[:3]):
        cols = list(zip(*g))
        row = ['\n'.join(value for value in col if value) for col in cols[3:]]
        csv_output.writerow([*k, *row])
```

Which gives an `output.csv` file containing:

```
Firewall,zone-Context,Policy,Source,Destination,Application,Action
fw_name,zone_a==>zone_b,policy1,"172.25.41.0/24
172.25.60.0/24","172.27.16.38/32
172.27.16.48/32","TCP_9090
TCP_8080",Permit
fw_name,zone_x==>zone_y,policy2,"172.25.41.0/24
172.25.60.0/24","172.27.16.38/32
172.27.16.48/32","TCP_9090
TCP_2020",Permit
```